# Open low tcp port from ROS node

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently writing a node that uses a 3rd party library. This library listens for multi-cast data streaming on port 1001. The problem I'm running into is that it requires root privileges to bind to this port (or any port <= 1023).

There isn't anything I can do to change the port number that I'm aware of, and (a) I don't want to have to run the node as root, especially since this node is likely gong to be distributed, and (b) as far as I can tell running the node as root isn't possible even if I wanted too.

Does anybody know what I might be able to do to listen to port 1001 from within my node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93776/open-low-tcp-port-from-ros-node/) by [dpkoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/7781/dpkoch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 132 on 2013-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Port under 1024 cannot be open by non-root user on Linux by design.
You can play with the [uid/gid permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) to allow the node to run with root capabilities while being able to be launched by anyone but this does not solve the safety issue.

I don't know your library but it is unlikely that it binds a low port number without allowing you to change the port number. And if it really is the case, I guess you should send a bug report to them.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dpkoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/7781/dpkoch/) on 2013-10-24**:
The library I'm using is an SDK that has the port number hard-coded (it streams data from software on a remote computer that also has the port hard-coded). I'll work with the SKD developers on finding a more permanent solution, but I was at least able to test my node using the setuid flag. Thanks!

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-10-24**:
Great to hear this! Be extra careful with setuid as the process will run as root. Good luck.